# Diff b/w @NotNull annotation and nullable in @Column

Tags: hibernate, javax.validation

I have created a model with the following field

```
   @NotNull
    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
```

When I try to post a JSON without the postal code, It should not be saved to the database. That's the reason I have used @NotNull annotation, But to my surprise, It's saving to the database even though the postal code is empty.

So then, I used

```
@Column(name="postal_code" , nullable=false) //instead of @NotNull
```

By changing the code as shown in the above, It's not saving to the database with an empty postal code.

My question is why it's not working with @NotNull and what is the diff b/w @NotNull and nullable

Comment: Do you have Hibernate Validator or another Bean Validation framework on your classpath?  It sounds like the bean validation integration that modifies the domain model at bootstrap isn't happening.

Comment: Yes, I have hibernate validator. That is the reason for that issue?

Comment: Are you configuring `javax.persistence.validation.mode` anywhere?

Comment: No, I didn't configure

Comment: Perhaps enable debug or trace logging and see whether or not there are any messages logged during startup of Hibernate that might explain why the domain model isn't being modified.